# CodeIgniter DataMapper include_related only including one related model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have a Product_faq class which has a `$has_many` relationship to a Product class.  I have a Product class which has a `$has_many` relationship to the Product_faq class.  These two classes are joined using a `product_faqs_products` table.

I am trying to use the following code to retrieve a specific Product_faq along with the Products associated to it:

```
$faqs = new Product_faq();
faqs->include_related('product', null, true, true)->get_by_id(25);

foreach($faqs->product as $product){
    echo $product->id.PHP_EOL;
}
```

There are three products related to this product_faq, but this code is only outputting the first one.  Is this the intended functionality?  Is there any way for me to include all of the related products on this query?

Answer (score 0):

`get_by_id` function returns one row because of getting `product_faqs_products`.`id` that primary key is 25.

Try `where` clause with `foreign_key` following:

```
$faqs->include_related('product', null, true, true)->where('product_id', 25);
```

Comment: Hi Bora.  I don't think that's correct.  `get_by_id` is used here because I'm only getting one Product_faq, however, I want that object to contain a "product" attribute that is an array of the three Product objects related to this Product_faq.  For example, doing it this way works:  `$faqs = new Product_faq();$faqs->get_by_id(25);$faqs->product->get();`